# Count number of unique entries occuring more than twice for a given criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table and would like to create a formula which would count the number of values that occur three times or more based on column B matching a criteria.

Example: If in column B value is Location1, then count how many values in column A occur more than 2 times. The answer should be 2 for Location1 -- values '4' and '7' occur more than 2 times.

could anyone help me with this formula? I would like the answer fill in another cell... for use in a larger sheet of stats.

```
Value Location
1 Location1
1 Location20
2 Location20
4 Location1
4 Location1
4 Location1
5 Location1
7 Location1
7 Location1
7 Location1
7 Location1
```

edit: Found my own solution. Used the "better" version formula [found here](https://superuser.com/questions/654200/how-a-count-of-values-which-have-more-than-1-occurance-in-a-column) (in the first answer).

The formula found in that link is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(A2:A10,A2:A10)>1)/COUNTIF(A2:A10,A2:A10&""))
```

I am familiar with COUNTIF and COUNTIFS, so I added another condition and used COUNTIFS.

The final solution would be

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIFS(A2:A12,A2:A12,B2:B12,"Location1")>2)/COUNTIF(A2:A12,A2:A12&""))
```

I'm not familiar with SUMPRODUCT, so the comparison of the count to ">2" feels unintuitive.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Why would the answer be 3 for `Location1`? Wouldn't it be 2 because it appears more than twice for values `4` and `7`? Also where do you want the output to be? Do you have a list of all `Locations` somewhere? Please edit your question to include/clarify this information.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited based on your comments. For the list of `Locations`, just assume that it's something like `Location1` to `Location20`, and I have this list enumerated as well.

Answer (score 1):

Trickier solution than I expected.

*Assuming your* `Value` *column only contains integers*, this will work:

```
= SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$12,D2,$A$2:$A$12,
  ROW(INDEX($A:$A,MIN($A$2:$A$12)):INDEX($A:$A,MAX($A$2:$A$12))))>2)+0)
```

See below for working example. I changed some of your data just to show it works for multiple values and locations.

[image]